# JavaScript Rating after refreshpage

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function to display rating.
When user click on stars to rate I need to display the "Thank you for rating" message and when user refresh the page I need to display "thank you for rating" message instead of "Rate this article".
Below is my code: could any one help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var sMax;   // Isthe maximum number of stars
var holder; // Is the holding pattern for clicked state
var preSet; // Is the PreSet value onces a selection has been made
var rated;

// Rollover for image Stars //



function rating(num){
    sMax = 0;   // Isthe maximum number of stars
    for(n=0; n<num.parentNode.childNodes.length; n++){
        if(num.parentNode.childNodes[n].nodeName == "A"){
            sMax++; 
        }
    }
    
    if(!rated){
        s = num.id.replace("_", ''); // Get the selected star
        a = 0;
        for(i=1; i<=sMax; i++){     
            if(i<=s){
                document.getElementById("_"+i).className = "on";
                document.getElementById("rateStatus").innerHTML = num.title;    
                holder = a+1;
                a++;
            }else{
                document.getElementById("_"+i).className = "";
            }
        }
    }
}

// For when you roll out of the the whole thing //
function off(me){
    if(!rated){
        if(!preSet){    
            for(i=1; i<=sMax; i++){     
                document.getElementById("_"+i).className = "";
                document.getElementById("rateStatus").innerHTML = me.parentNode.title;
            }
        }else{
            rating(preSet);
            document.getElementById("rateStatus").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ratingSaved").innerHTML;
        }
    }
}

// When you actually rate something //
function rateIt(me){
    if(!rated){
        document.getElementById("rateStatus").innerHTML = document.getElementById("ratingSaved").innerHTML + " :: "+me.title;
        preSet = me;
        rated=1;
        sendRate(me);
        rating(me);
    }
}

// Send the rating information somewhere using Ajax or something like that.
function sendRate(sel){
    alert("Your rating was: "+sel.title);
}


</script>





<form id="form1">


<span id="rateStatus">Rate This Article:</span>
<span id="ratingSaved">Thank you for rating.</span> 
<div id="rateMe" title="Rate Me...">
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_1" title="ehh..." onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"></a>
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_2" title="Not Bad" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"></a>
    <a onclick="rateIt(this)" id="_3" title="Pretty Good" onmouseover="rating(this)" onmouseout="off(this)"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you post HTML and explain what the problem is...

Comment: I have added my HTML..When user click on star to rate I need to display thank you for rating message and I should remove the rated stars....When the user refreshes the already rated page I need to display thank you for rating message..

Comment: I came to know how to display thank you for rating and hide the rated stars:document.getElementById("rateme").innerHTML.style.visibility = 'hidden';

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the cookie as soon as user rate the article and check that cookie value when you load the page again to confirm if the article is already loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also fetch the current ratings of this article from the server if you are refreshing the page anyways

Comment: then previous answer is good enough. let me share some reference code for cookie handling with you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, and what you do is going to depend on your requirements.

The big issue is one of permanence. By that, if I rate something and get the Thank You message should I see that if I look at the same page from my phone browser, or a browser on another computer? Otherwise, is it simply a message that needs to show once and you don't care if I see the "Please rate" option again later?

Based on your question about saving state between page refreshes, it sounds like your needs are more on the side of saving permanence.

Ultimately, the only way to *guarantee* that the rating state is saved permanently is to tie it into a user account on the backend (server) application. That way, when I view the same page from other browsers, or after a long time, then the server can lookup in the database and see that "Geuis rated this, show the Thank You message".

If you only need to show the Thank You for a short amount of time, you can store a key in a temporary cache like memcache. On each page refresh, a short piece of javascript can make an xhr request to your cache server to check if I've rated the page or not. Eventually the key falls out of the cache, so maybe in an hour or a day when I go back to see the page then I'll be prompted to rate the page. This is a semi-permanent solution, but it does work across any device or browser as long as its tied into an account.

The most fragile, but easiest, solution to implement is purely client-side. Here, your options are to either a) store the rated/not rated value in a cookie, or b) use localStorage. In either situation, it will let store the state. *But* cookies and localStorage are not transferred between devices or browsers. localStorage won't expire, but eventually cookies will. Also, the user can eventually decide to clear out their cookies and localStorage caches and would set the state back to "Rate me".

I'm not providing any code samples because, as I hope you can see, the answer really lies first in *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish along the spectrum of permanence.

And just to say it, there's really no such thing as anonymous permanence. I.e. you can't have a user to be anonymous to your site yet save their voting state permanently in a way that transfers between browsers. You *have* to have something akin to a server-side account to do that.